# Is it possible to trigger an AWS Fargate task upon an event being published to AWS SNS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, backend, devops

I'm new to AWS. I'm currently assigned a task where in I need to decouple a long running task in it's own task from our monolithic application so that we can redeploy our application without waiting for this long running task to be completed before redeploying. This tasked is triggered by an event in our monolithic application, I was specifically tasked to convert this into a fargate task. But is there a way to trigger a fargate task via an event that is published to AWS SNS? I asked chatgpt and chatgpt said that this can be done but AWS Lambda will be notified by the event and AWS Lambda will be the one who will trigger the fargate task. Are there any other solutions besides this? Thank you

I have tried asking chatgpt and googling

Comment: You may want to read [ask]